# redis-server.service: Can't open PID file

Tags: ubuntu, redis

When running `sudo systemctl status redis`, I see this error message:

```
systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /run/redis/redis-server.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
```

However, Redis seems to work fine. I can run redis-cli, do the traditional ping test, create a database, etc. The `/var/run/redis` folder is owned by redis, so is the `redis-server.service`. I did set `supervised` to `systemd` in `redis.conf` since I'm on Ubuntu and `systemctl` tells me the server is running and active.

Should I worry/anticipate an issue or is it nothing?

Comment: Answered here - https://serverfault.com/questions/981799/redis-server-servicecannot-open-pid-file-var-ru

Comment: @Malgo: No, this is not the answer to this issue. This issue is also present in the question but ignored by the sole response as it was unrelated to the main issue.

Comment: Late to the game, but it looks like its fine. I have the same message and tried logging into the server, adding a key and then restarting the server. Result: the key was still there. So any data is preserved 